# Roslyn semantic model with solution

Tags: c#, roslyn

I load my solution:

```
var workspace = Workspace.LoadSolution(path);
```

Now I would like create a semantic model with any file in this solution. How Can I do this? I tried used LINQ but I don't now how create a semantic model to analysis classdeclaration, etc.

```
ISolution semanticModel = tree.GetSemanticModel();
```

not work ;(

Answer (score 3):

You can get the semantic model from a document instance.

```
var someSemanticModel = 
    workspace.CurrentSolution
             .Projects.First()
             .Documents.First()
             .GetSemanticModel();
```

Comment: doing this I get an error when trying to resolv that belongs to a AST that's different from the current document. It's seems the semantic model is related to the document and not the solution

Comment: The semantic model relates to a syntax tree, which typically relates to a single document